# If $J$ is a maximal ideal in a commutative ring $R$ with unity, what is the ideal $K$ such that $J \subset K \subseteq R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, proof-explanation, ideals

I’m reading this proof: [Maximal Ideal iff Quotient is Field](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Field).

My question concerns just a step in the proof of the forward implication. There the author lets $x \in R \setminus J$, and $K := \{j + rx: j\in J, r \in R\} \subseteq R$. The idea is to show that $K$ is also an ideal, and that we have the chain of inclusion $J \subset K \subseteq R$. Since $J$ is maximal, we’d have $K = R$, and from there some further arguments show that $(x + J)$ has a multiplicative inverse in $R/J$.

While I can work through the algebraic manipulations, I was hoping to see an easier argument as to why $1_R$ must be in $K$ (not just because we’ve argued that $K = R$).

I am in fact, in another exercise, trying to show that a particular ideal is maximal, by setting up a similar chain of inclusion and arguing that $1_R$ is in the ideal “in between”. So that’s why I’m asking about $K$.

==================================================================

**Edit:** It’s been suggested that I should inquire about the problem that actually bothers me. So here it is:

> Show that, in $k[x]$, for $c \in k$, the ideal $(x-c)$ is maximal.

I’m aware of the proof involving a homomorphism $\varphi: k[x] \to k$ such that $\operatorname{ker}\varphi = (x-c)$. I’d need that lemma above for the argument to work. Here, if I set $m_c := (x-c) \subset K \subseteq k[x]$, can I somehow show that $1_{k[x]} \in K$?

Comment: Actually, since you know there exists some $\phi$ with ker$\phi =(x-c)$. Can you show what $\phi (p(x))$ is, for some polynomials $p(x)$ in $k[x]$?

Comment: It’s the mapping $p(x) \mapsto p(c)$ (or $x \mapsto c)$, isn’t it?